# RestRequest Param Host not autocreate

Tags: rest, http, delphi

Using Delphi 10, I have a `TRESTClient` with `TRESTRequest` to access an API.

I can't reach the server using its DNS hostname. There is a DNS problem on my network, and using the hostname I reach the wrong server. So I must use the server's IP address instead. But the API expects the `Host` request header to be the DNS hostname.

So I try to put a header like `Host: auth-x.de` in the request, like this:

```
RESTClient1.AddParameter('Auto', 'blau', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER);
RESTClient1.AddParameter('Host', 'auth-x.de', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER);
```

But when I send the request to the IP address, the component overwrites my `Host` header with the IP address.

The header `Auto: blau` (just for test) is sent just fine.

How can I prevent my `Host` header from being automatically overwritten?

Comment: That kind of information should have been put in the question. I have made that edit for you. You can delete the previous comment